# Connecting to cache instance (csession) remotely

Tags: intersystems, intersystems-cache-studio

Is there a way to connect to cache instance (csession) remotely?

Let's say the intersystems is on a container, and I want to use `csession` on the remote server from my local machine, is there a way (without direct ssh) to run the cache instance?

I'm looking for an alternative way of these steps:

1- scp the cache script into the box

2- ssh into the box

3- run the csesion on the box

Any comments is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You could use telnet ([encrypted](http://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCAS_ssltls#GCAS_ssltls_telnet_svr)) But this wouldn't allow you to load scripts local to your machine.

One way would be to have your scripts in a git repository and add the loading of them into your instance as [post-receive](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) hook.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using https://intersystems-ru.github.io/webterminal/.

That is "web-based terminal for InterSystems Caché".